# React, what does "e" do?

Tags: react-native

i have this code:

```
 function MyControlledInput() {

 const [altaData, setAltaData] = useState('');


 const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setAltaData(e.target.value);
 return (
    <>
        <div>Input value: {value}</div>
        <input
            type='text'
            name='name'
            onChange={onChangeHandler}
            value={altaData}
        />
        <button onClick={ShowSentenceByWord}>Activate Lasers</button>
)}
```

can someone please explain what "e" does? i don't understand how the user data end up being in the "altaData" variable, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This "e" is the short term for event, which is related to the native html [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

In the link above you can check the details about its content, but most likely you'll be using `e.target.value` to get the newest value from the input.

And how you're using this value to call the `setAltaData`, the result of that will be the `altData` being changed.

That's the purpose of this [react-hooks#useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)